# HTML div being overlayed by section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to lay out a page using sections but am running into some problems.  My code is below...

https://jsfiddle.net/ytv4zp4b/

```
<section>
    <div class="width">
        Test Content
                <div class="sharing">
            <div class="sharingsocial">
                Social Links
            </div>
            <div class="sharingprint">
                Print Link
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    Footer
</section>

section{background-color:grey;}
.width{background-color:red;max-width:500px;margin:auto;}
.sharing{max-width:500px;margin:auto;}
.sharingsocial{float:left;background:green;}
.sharingprint{float:right;background:yellow;}
```

I can't work out why the .sharing div is overlayed by the footer section, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your problem is the floating without clearing anything. Try replacing the ```float: left``` for the ```display: inline-block``` and see if this is your desired result. Also check [this tutorial about CSS layout](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) highly recommended :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

The CSS float property is causing all subsequent elements to float as well. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) for more on floats.

### The Solution

You must set `clear: both` in order to stop other elements from floating as well.

You can accomplish this by adding the following to your CSS:

```
.width:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

### Demo

```css
section{
  background-color: grey;
}

.width{
  background-color:red;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:auto;
  }
  
.width:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

.sharing{
  max-width:500px;
  margin:auto;
}

.sharingsocial{
  float:left;
  background:green;
}
.sharingprint{
  float:right;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="width">
        Test Content
 <div class="sharing">
            <div class="sharingsocial">
                Social Links
            </div>
            <div class="sharingprint">
                Print Link
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    Footer
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add following div before closing the `.sharing` div.

Code :

`<div style="clear:both;">
            </div>`

https://jsfiddle.net/ytv4zp4b/2/

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `float:left` to `display:inline-block` for `.sharingsocial` it will work!
here is updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytv4zp4b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `overflow: hidden` on `.sharing` to trigger a new new block formatting context

https://jsfiddle.net/ytv4zp4b/3/

*Note: that this method will clip your content in case you want to go over the `.sharing` container boundaries.*